# How can I create a list of top donors using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how I can create a list of top donors, in which the user who donates the most is in the first position of the list.

In order to donate, you must be logged in

How can I do something like that using php and mysql?

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only how much i understand your question.

First you need to create table for donors which the storage of their data, and 2nd is to make table for donate which holds the donator.

Then to sort the donator by donated the most, just use **COUNT sql query** to get the highest donate number.